# Visio ActiveDocument.Close() error using C#

Tags: c#, visio

I implemented a new button called "Close" and the "code behind" looks like this:

```
   public static void ForceCloseAll(Visio.Documents docs)
   {
       while (docs.Count > 0)
       {
           docs.Application.ActiveDocument.Close();
       }
   }
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
   "The operation cannot be performed while doing in-place editing".
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't save your document

```
public static void ForceCloseAll(Visio.Documents docs)
{
    while (docs.Count > 0)
    {
       docs.Application.ActiveDocument.Saved = true;
       docs.Application.ActiveDocument.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @RodrigoCampos You need set is "saved" file.